# Use WebRtc to deliver hls to Safari on IOS

Tags: webrtc, http-live-streaming

I found [this github repo](https://github.com/Novage/p2p-media-loader) which allows me to use WebRtc to deliver hls over the WebRtc Datachannel.
The Problem is that it does not support Safari on IOS.
The newest versions of Safari on IOS do support WebRtc datachannels and they have native support for hls playback.
This is my problem is it only possible to use WebRtc for data transfer on Browsers which support Media Source Extensions or can I also use WebRtc to deliver the .ts files to the Safari Browser on IOS?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer of P2P Media Loader and we are working on iOS support right now. Hopefully, we will have a prototype soon.

On iOS Safari you can exchange video and audio data using WebRTC Data Channels but you can not put that data and play into HTML video element without API like Media Source Extensions.

We are currently testing a different approach to do that on iOS Safari.

Comment: please let me know if your approach is successful.

Answer (score 0):

iOS Safari doesn't support Media Source Extensions of HTML5 video element.

Therefore, you cannot play synchronized audio and video on iOS Safari by any hand-made approaches that use various API such as Canvas, Web Audio API etc..
iOS Safari has two built-in methods for playing synchronized audio and video:

- a. Native HLS playback
- b. WebRTC PeerConnection

If you choose WebRTC PeerConnection, you will have to transcode AAC audio used in HLS to Opus audio required by WebRTC, and to transmux HLS to WebRTC.
Ugly, CPU-consuming and really pointless. What does it buy you? Why not to use native HLS playback on iOS Safari? But if you insist on option b, then there is number of software media servers that will do it for you.

Comment: Late answer: WebRTC does buy you something and that's low latency. The way HLS and DASH pull video chunks instead of letting the sever push data as soon as it's ready is ass backwards. "Low-Latency HLS" is very high latency and has issues with time sync just like LL-DASH.